# How to prevent xeTeX from inserting a space in front of 《 in a reference?

Tags: xetex

As it also happens in the title of this question, typing 《 (Unicode+300A, according to my reference) generates a large preceding space. I want to stop xeTex from displaying this space. I specifically want to suppress it within the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Start the document
\begin{document}
\cite[《儲小寶》]{jiejie}

\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{document.bib}
\end{document}
```

Where document.bib reads:

> @misc{jiejie,
>       author    = "Wei Wei",
>       title     = "姐姐和弟弟"
>   }

which produces:
[image]

Comment: I think it's the design of the font: the guillemets have the same width as the Chinese characters

Comment: @Bobyandbob I had the code ready before the question, it's just that I am texing on the IPad. So when I wanted to paste the code here, it was not possible to mark it. Even indent it line by line. Every time I did the iPad fixated on words it wanted to auto correct. I hope it's correct now.

Comment: If you are using `xeCJK` you should not load `inputenc`. Also `bibtex` really doesn't work with UTF-8 `.bib` files. I would recommend using `biblatex` + `biber` instead.

Comment: @AlanMunn very good! But it is ignored automatically and doesn't change the problem.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't suggesting it as a solution. It might be possible to use `\XeTeXinterchartoks` to add a negative kern to the guillemet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how the guillemets are designed.

You can modify how they behave, though.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{jiejie, author = "Wei Wei", title = "姐姐和弟弟" }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{《}{\makebox[\width][r]{《}}
\newunicodechar{》}{\makebox[.5\width][l]{》}}


% Start the document
\begin{document}

X《X》X

\cite[《儲小寶》]{jiejie}

[1, X]

\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A couple of notes:

1. `inputenc` does nothing with XeLaTeX, other than displaying a warning;
2. the argument to `\bibliography` should not have the `.bib` extension (it works with MiKTeX, but not with other TeX distributions);
3. the `filecontents*` environment is used only to make the example self-contained.